# pushing json data to array after adding a key value pair takes last value of the key pair

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to push a json object to an array after adding one more key pair value to it, but the resulting array is wrong with the last value of the pair,

```
  console.log("Followers")
  console.log(his_followers);     
  var data = { 
  createdAt: 1555674703
  //some more key pair values exist here
  }    

  his_followers.forEach(uid => {
    var tdata = data
    tdata.target_user = uid.followed_by
   console.log('tdata')
    console.log(tdata);
    followers_data.push(tdata)
  })
  console.log('Followers data')
  console.log(followers_data);
```

and this the output,

```
Followers
[ { followed_by: 'ramk' },
  { followed_by: 'balk' } ]
tdata
{ createdAt: 1555674703,
  target_user: 'ramk' }
tdata
{ createdAt: 1555674703,
  target_user: 'balk' }
Followers data
[ { createdAt: 1555674703,
    target_user: 'balk' },
  { createdAt: 1555674703,
    target_user: 'balk' } ]
```

As you see the followers_data target_user is wrong.. I have no clue why this is happening, any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is in `his_Followers` ?

Comment: it is in the output Followers
[ { followed_by: 'ramk' },
  { followed_by: 'balk' } ]

Comment: `tdata.target_user = uid.followed_by` updates `data` as well because they are both pointing to same reference. Try `var tdata = {...data}` to clone the object first

Comment: oh wow! I never knew that pointing the same reference..it is working now..thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)